# Prove that $\int_{E}fd\mu = 0\implies f= 0$ a.e with $f$ a positive measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I would like to prove that for a given measure space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ and a measurable function with values in the extended positive real line equipped with the sigma algebra generated by the borel sets we have :

$$
\int_{E}fd\mu = 0 \implies f = 0\quad a.e
$$

We know that there exists a increasing sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ that is :

$$
\forall x\in E,\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} : n>N\implies \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon
$$

We have that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : 0\leq f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ which implies

$$
\int_{E}f_nd\mu\leq\int_{E}f_{n+1}d\mu
$$

By the monotone convergence theorem, we know that $(\int_{E}f_{n}d\mu)_{n}$ converges to $\int_{E}fd\mu$ but since the sequence of integrals is increasing, this means that

$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : \int_{E} f_nd\mu = 0\implies \sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i^{n}\mu(A_i^{n}) = 0
$$

where $A_i^{n} = \{x\in E : f(x) = \alpha_i^{n}\}$. Since the simples functions are positive, this means that if $\alpha_i^{n}>0$ we have $\mu(A_i^{n}) =0$ which means that

$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N} : f_n = 0\quad a.e
$$

Now I would like to pursue the proof, but I realized that I am not convinced by the argument I wanted to use : conclude that since $f_n$ is a sequence of null functions, it converges to the null function, that is $f=0$ a.e.

So I would like to have your help on this please, in what direction can I go at this step ?

Thank you !

---

Thanks to geetha290krm here is the end of the proof :

If $x\in E$ is such that $f(x)>0$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n(x)>0$. Thus we have the following implications

$$
x\in \{ x\in E : f(x)>0\}\implies\exists n\in\mathbb{N} : f_n(x)>0
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\exists n\in\mathbb{N} : x\in \{x\in E : f_n(x) > 0\}\Longleftrightarrow x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{ x\in E : f_n(x)>0\}
$$

Thus

$$
\{ x\in E : f(x)>0\}\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{ x\in E : f_n(x)>0\}
$$

We see that $\{f_n>0\}\subset\{f_{n+1}>0\}$ since the sequence is increasing. It follows that

$$
\mu(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f_n>0\}) =lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu(\{f_n>0\}) = 0
$$

since we have shown that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $f_n=0$ a.e. Hence we have our conclusion since $0\leq\mu(\{f>0\})\leq \mu(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{f_n>0\}) = 0$

Comment: @geetha290krm Maybe I am missing something, but the question asks for functions with values in $[0, +\infty]$...?

Comment: @noam.szyfer The question was edited about 38 minutes after it was posted.

Comment: $\{f>0\} \subseteq \bigcup_n \{f_n>0\} $

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry for these mistakes !

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks ! I have updated the post let me know if I am wrong at some point.

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Comment: There is potentially a small mistake in this line $\{f>0\}\subset\bigcup_{n>N}\{f_n>0\}\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, by the way you stated the approximation by simple functions, the convergence is pointwise so the $N$ may change for each $x$. However that step was not needed to conclude $\bigcup_n \{f_n>0\}$.

Comment: @FZan Yes actually what I wrote is ambiguous since it depends on $N$ for each x thank you and the notation $\{ f(x)>0\}$ has no more sense since $x$ is fixed. How do you prove the inclusion so ?

Comment: You have already shown that for each $x$ there is an $n$ so that $f_{n}(x)>0$.

Comment: @FZan I have updated the post trying to put all the details to justify the inclusion, I think it's okay now but let me know if not.

Comment: Well, $0 \leq m\{x \in E | f(x) \geq 1 /n \} \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_{E} f = 0$

Comment: @Matematleta More lightning indeed !